# How to not Escape : Characters in Ant propertyfile task

Tags: ant

I have thousands of properties in my property file and I want to change only one property like the following.

```
<propertyfile  file="${mypropetyfile}">
    <entry  key="jndiname" value="java:comp/env/wm/default"/>
</propertyfile>
```

but in the property file I am getting the property value with an extra `\`:

```
jndiname=java\:comp/env/wm/default
```

I tried with the `<echo>` task but it removes other properties. I also tried by concatenation like following in this case also I am getting extra `\`

```
<propertyfile  file="${mypropetyfile}">
    <entry  key="jndiname" default="" operation="+" value="java:comp/env/wm/default"/>
</propertyfile>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine here.

Answer (score 5):

The `\` before the `:` is an escape character. Although it's not necessary here because the `:` is not part of the key, but is part of the value, it doesn't hurt either. Using Properties.load() to load this properties file will unescape the `:`. You should not care about the escape.

Comment: It seems that Apache log4j isn't aware of that. \ symbols go unaffected straight into your conversion pattern and then into log files.

Comment: To be fair to Ant, it's probably using the standard Java property writer which escapes colons because they're an alternative (that noone uses) for the equals .. see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29. BUT since many users of properties files can't deal with it (it seems) it should be optional

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into the same problem changing a property file read by Websphere 6.1 & ended up having to do this workaround:

```
<property name="jndi.example" value="java:comp/env/example" />

<propertyfile file="jdbc.properties">
    <entry key="datasource.example.jndi" operation="=" value="@EXAMPLE"/>
</propertyfile>

<!-- set tokens to property values because ant wants to 'escape the colon' -->
<replace file="jdbc.properties" token="@EXAMPLE" value="${jndi.example}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The 'best answer' isn't really addressing the problem. The Properties.load() is not the answer as in the case (which is highly likely), you won't control the 'other side' that will be consuming the properties file.

It doesn't appear you can set the `<propertyfile/>` to not do this. Seems like a bug to me.

The `<replace>` suggestion seems like the best course of action imo.

Answer (score 1):

I found that when I used the echo task the entry came out as expected\desired in the file.

However, if I ran the propertyfile task afterwards to populate the same file with some values, it escaped all the colons in the file.

To get around this I simply ensured I ran the propertyfile task first, then the echo.